# Read config file from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, config, configurationmanager

I'm creating a web application, which calls a DLL to run unit tests, I also have another DLL(DataAccessLayer) which performs connections and performs queries to SQL which references the main DLL. Both the DLLs use the same config file to read settings.

When running application from VS, the application is working fine. However when the web app is deployed to IIS, it seems the DLLs are unable to read the settings from the config file.

After some research I found that I might have to explicitly define the configuration elements in the web.config file, however I don't know how to implement this. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I'm actually retrieving the settings using the ConfigurationManager with the following code:-

```
   public string GetValue(string key)
   {
       var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("path to dll");
       strKeyValue = appConfig.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;



       return strKeyValue;
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I guess that the reading of config file is creating confusion, you can clear it out or can get some idea by looking at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juBDM3fb-i0

Answer (score 6):

Use `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HelloWorldKey"];` to read AppSettings from the web.config.

Comment: the settings are not in web.config, they are in a separate App.config which is used by the dll i'm calling.

Comment: Then move them to the web.config - .NET will overwrite the dll settings with the ones from the web.config. Use the app.config as default settings and access them with propterties.settings inside the dll.
BTW: configuring a dll isn't neccessary most times - just pass the configuration as parameters in your calls.

Answer (score 0):

Just set all the appSettings values used by the DLL you mention, directly in the web.config PRIOR to deploying the app. You don't need to modify this at run-time (and you shouldn't anyway, since any modification to the web.config will cause the application to restart)

Comment: so i put all appSettings of my config file in web.config and then in my dll i use the WebConfigurationManager to retrieve the value from the web.config?

Comment: The DLL will automatically read the values from the Web.config. You should use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings on ALL projects. I believe the WebConfigurationManager is deprecated.

Comment: @Krafo, use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]`. And you have to explicitly add to your dll a reference to `System.Configuration` (it is normally not included by default in dll projects by Visual Studio).

Comment: This is exactly how I would like it to behave, but it doesn't. Web.config does not override appSettings values of the machine.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to access connection string

```
string filePath= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pathfile"].ToString();
```

Web config Fie

```
<configuration>
       ....
     <appSettings>
       <add key="Pathfile" value="Path to dll"/>
     </appSettings>
    ....
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `connectionstring` or `AppSetting` or `ApplicationSettings` used in you app.config into your web.config, I understand this is a manual task but is the only way that the config will read the settings.